# Creating a split title for Drupal Webform

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

and I am trying to make a webform that looks like this:

---

SOME TITLE

some body content

Form Title 1

Label 1   (field1)

Label 2   (field2)

Label 3   (field3)

Form Title 2

Label 4   (field4)

Label 5   (field5)

---

So my question is, how do I tell the webform module that I want a "Form Title 1" and "Form Title 2" which does not have a input value?

I tried using using page-break, but it isnt what I want, as I am trying to create just a split title.

Essentially it is one form.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm the solutions seems to be so obvious that no one bothered to reply..

Basically all I needed to do is to add a "Markup" type, and literally type in the HTML

e.g.  Form Title